# Permission Denied Error During Update of a Local MSOffice Add-In from Network

Tags: vba, powerpoint, add-in

I am attempting to write a procedure in PowerPoint 2003 that will allow automatic updating of an installed add-in. The general process is as follows:

1. Uninstall the add-in

   ```
   For Each objAddIn In Application.AddIns
       If UCase(objAddIn.Name) = UCase(AddInName) Then
           With objAddIn
               .Registered = msoFalse
               .AutoLoad = msoFalse
               .Loaded = msoFalse
           End With
       End If
   Next
   ```
2. Delete the file from the local Add-Ins directory

   ```
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If objFSO.FileExists(FileName) Then
       Set objFSO = Nothing
       Kill FileName
   End If
   ```
3. Copy over the file from the network location
4. Install the updated add-In

Upon reaching step 2, any attempt at **deleting the file** post-uninstall using either the FileSystemObject or a straight `Kill` inevitably generates `Run-time error '70': Permission denied`. If I hit Debug and then play, it runs through as if there was never a problem.

*Side note: I realize I can use FSO to overwrite the local file, but that gives me the same run-time error.*

I'm guessing the problem has to do with some aspect of the file being in use, but I can't figure out how to "release" the old add-in so that the underlying file can be deleted.

Does anyone have insight that can help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove it from the Addins Collection before it can get physically deleted. Put this, right after your `End With`:

```
Application.AddIns.Remove objAddIn.Name
```

Comment: sadly, that did not work. The error persists even though the Add-In is removed from the Collection. Oddly, if I put a break at that line, run it, then continue along the process it continues without issue. I tried adding a Sleep delay, but that did nothing.

Comment: @variant: Wow, interesting, I haven't seen this before, but now I see it. And you're right about the breakpoint - if it breaks and continues, no problem deleting the file. I've determined that the addin is still open when the code tries to delete it - `Open addinPath For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1` where `addinPath = objAddIn.Name`.

Comment: Er... what does that "Open addinPath For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1" do?

Comment: @variant: it's just a sample. it's a way of opening a file to read/write without resorting to FSO. See: http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080058958&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD%2EDEV&Version=14&pid=CH080058918&CTT=4

Answer (score 0):

The KB Article that refers to a VBA function you can use to CHECK for a locked file is here.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209189

It contains a simple function you can add to your VBA to check that a file is not locked and uses the same code sample that Otaku refers to in his answer.

What I would do is...

Replace the Kill Filename line in your code

```
If FileLocked(Filename) = True Then  
SetAttr Filename, vbNormal  
Kill Filename  
End If
```

*Where FileLocked is a custom function referred to in KB209189
**If this doesn't work, reply back, we could also look at replacing the Kill statement above with a lower level Win32 function that does the same thing (but perhaps more throughly). :D

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I ended up building a workaround that eventually evolved into autoupdating. Perhaps this will help someone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: No problem. If file locking is a constant issue I would say your solution is a better approach.